Does Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein for vector spaces imply choice?
The answers to this question say it is consistent with the negation of choice for there to be vector spaces that don't satisfy the CSB property (that is, there can be two vector spaces that embed into eachother but are not isomorphic). But they don't say whether this is the case in every model where choice fails. Can there be a model of ZF+not(C) where vector spaces satisfy CSB?
